# Unable to render reactDOM

Tags: reactjs

I'm just starting out to learn React, trying to render react from my localhost, but this error seems to be showing, any advice?

[image]

Comment: How did you create your react-app?

Comment: I just started to npm install the dependencies react react-dom and reactscripts to my terminal,  do I need to do the express setup to load ?

Comment: No, you don't need an express for that. Did you config your webpack/babel?

Comment: I guess it's much easier if you use `https://create-react-app.dev/` when starting to learn Reactjs

Comment: Thanks Ryan! WIll check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what I can assume, you are probably trying to run a react app in NodeJS, and this wont work.
Since React uses JSX, you'l need to transpile it before it will work there too.

One way to make this work is, develop a react app independently, once your done make a build of the app and then place it inside you NodeJS app folder

Or maybe follow [this](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment) and [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#recommended-toolchains)